# SQL complexo com MySQL

Tags: mysql

Eu eu tenho estas tabelas e preciso fazer um comando sql para receber esta resposta. Eu utilizo o MySQL.

[image: tabela_estudantes_identificacao]
[image: tabela_turmas_has_estudantes]
[image: tabela_sexo_identificacao]

[image: tabela_situacao_final]

[image: tabela_turmas_identificacao]
  [image: resultado_esperado]


***Eu tentei assim e retorna zero em todos os códigos:***

```
    SELECT
    COUNT( ei.sexo_id ) AS total_sexo_masculino, 
        the.situacao_final_id 
    FROM 
        turmas_has_estudantes the 
    INNER JOIN
        estudantes_identificacao ei
    ON
       ( the.estudantes_identificacao_id = ei.id 
         AND the.situacao_final_id != 3 
         AND the.situacao_final_id != 5 
         AND the.situacao_final_id != 6 )
    WHERE
         ei.sexo_id = 2
    AND
        the.turmas_id = 492
```

```
   SELECT
   COUNT( ei.sexo_id ) AS total_sexo_masculino, 
        the.situacao_final_id 
   FROM 
        turmas_has_estudantes the 
   INNER JOIN
        estudantes_identificacao ei
   ON
        the.estudantes_identificacao_id = ei.id
   WHERE
        ei.sexo_id = 2
   AND
        the.turmas_id = 492
   AND 
        the.situacao_final_id != 3 
   AND 
        the.situacao_final_id != 5 
   AND 
        the.situacao_final_id != 6
```

***Se eu fizer assim, retorna 1:***

```
   SELECT
        COUNT( ei.sexo_id ) AS total_sexo_masculino, 
        the.situacao_final_id 
    FROM 
         turmas_has_estudantes the 
    INNER JOIN
         estudantes_identificacao ei
    ON
         ( the.estudantes_identificacao_id = ei.id 
           AND the.situacao_final_id = 6 )
    WHERE
         ei.sexo_id = 2
    AND
         the.turmas_id = 492
```

Comment: você não vai conseguir fazer isso com um único `select` simples. você precisa computar coisas diferentes que precisam de um `group by` ou `where` e ainda estão em tabelas diferentes, por isso você vai precisar de múltiplos selects para trazer o *resultado esperado*

Comment: No seu "Resultado Esperado" seria o resultado de várias consultas, e não de uma apenas, tem certeza que é isso que quer? O mais correto seria fazer as consultas separadas, de sexo, situação e total.

Comment: Creio que essa consulta exija uniões, portanto são consultas inerentemente distintas

Comment: Eu preciso retornar o resultado de todas as turmas. O turmas_id = 492 é apenas uma referencia

Comment: @LuisSouza fiz um exemplo prático que irá servir para qualquer situação a mais que surgir

Comment: Havia um erro na foto da tabela turmas_identificação. Corrigido

Answer (score 3):

Fiz o SQL genérico:

```
select
  'Total Estudantes' as Resultado, count(*)  as Total
from 
  ESTUDANTES_IDENTIFICACAO
union
select 
  CONCAT('Sexo ', b.sexo), count(*) 
from 
  ESTUDANTES_IDENTIFICACAO a
  inner join SEXO_IDENTIFICACAO b on b.id = a.sexo_id
group by
  b.sexo
union
select 
  CONCAT('Situacao Final ', IFNULL(b.situacao_final_id, "ND")), count(*) 
from 
  TURMAS_HAS_ESTUDANTES a
  left join SITUACAO_FINAL b on b.id = a.situacao_final
group by
  b.situacao_final_id
```

#### Exemplo prático

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04353fe/10

#### Resultado Final

```
|                     Resultado | Total |
|-------------------------------|-------|
|              Total Estudantes |    15 |
|                 Sexo Feminino |     6 |
|                Sexo Masculino |     9 |
|             Situacao Final ND |    10 |
| Situacao Final Reclassificado |     1 |
|     Situacao Final Remanejado |     2 |
|    Situacao Final Transferido |     2 |
```

#### Exemplo Prático Filtrando Turma

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b625e5/3

#### Resultado Filtrando Turma

```
|                     Resultado | Total |
|-------------------------------|-------|
|              Total Estudantes |     6 |
|                 Sexo Feminino |     2 |
|                Sexo Masculino |     4 |
|             Situacao Final ND |     2 |
| Situacao Final Reclassificado |     1 |
|     Situacao Final Remanejado |     1 |
|    Situacao Final Transferido |     2 |
```

#### Dados da estrutura

```
create table ESTUDANTES_IDENTIFICACAO (
  id int not null,
  nome varchar(50),
  sexo_id int,
  deficiancia varchar(50)
);

insert into ESTUDANTES_IDENTIFICACAO values (1, 'nome_1', 1, null);
insert into ESTUDANTES_IDENTIFICACAO values (2, 'nome_2', 1, null);
insert into ESTUDANTES_IDENTIFICACAO values (3, 'nome_3', 2, null);
insert into ESTUDANTES_IDENTIFICACAO values (4, 'nome_4', 1, null);
insert into ESTUDANTES_IDENTIFICACAO values (5, 'nome_5', 2, null);
insert into ESTUDANTES_IDENTIFICACAO values (6, 'nome_6', 1, null);
insert into ESTUDANTES_IDENTIFICACAO values (7, 'nome_7', 1, null);
insert into ESTUDANTES_IDENTIFICACAO values (8, 'nome_8', 2, null);
insert into ESTUDANTES_IDENTIFICACAO values (9, 'nome_9', 1, null);
insert into ESTUDANTES_IDENTIFICACAO values (10, 'nome_10', 2, null);
insert into ESTUDANTES_IDENTIFICACAO values (11, 'nome_11', 2, null);
insert into ESTUDANTES_IDENTIFICACAO values (12, 'nome_12', 1, null);
insert into ESTUDANTES_IDENTIFICACAO values (13, 'nome_13', 1, null);
insert into ESTUDANTES_IDENTIFICACAO values (14, 'nome_14', 2, null);
insert into ESTUDANTES_IDENTIFICACAO values (15, 'nome_15', 1, null);

create table SEXO_IDENTIFICACAO (
  id int not null,
  sexo varchar(50)
);

insert into SEXO_IDENTIFICACAO values (1, 'Masculino');
insert into SEXO_IDENTIFICACAO values (2, 'Feminino');

create table TURMAS_HAS_ESTUDANTES (
  id int not null,
  turma_id int,
  estudante_id int,
  situacao_final int  
);

insert into TURMAS_HAS_ESTUDANTES values (1, 492, 1, null);
insert into TURMAS_HAS_ESTUDANTES values (2, 492, 2, 3);
insert into TURMAS_HAS_ESTUDANTES values (3, 492, 3, null);
insert into TURMAS_HAS_ESTUDANTES values (4, 492, 4, 5);
insert into TURMAS_HAS_ESTUDANTES values (5, 492, 5, 6);
insert into TURMAS_HAS_ESTUDANTES values (6, 492, 6, 5);
insert into TURMAS_HAS_ESTUDANTES values (7, 493, 7, null);
insert into TURMAS_HAS_ESTUDANTES values (8, 493, 8, null);
insert into TURMAS_HAS_ESTUDANTES values (9, 493, 9, 3);
insert into TURMAS_HAS_ESTUDANTES values (10, 493, 10, null);
insert into TURMAS_HAS_ESTUDANTES values (11, 493, 11, null);
insert into TURMAS_HAS_ESTUDANTES values (12, 493, 12, null);
insert into TURMAS_HAS_ESTUDANTES values (13, 494, 13, null);
insert into TURMAS_HAS_ESTUDANTES values (14, 494, 14, null);
insert into TURMAS_HAS_ESTUDANTES values (15, 494, 15, null);

create table SITUACAO_FINAL (
   id int not null,
   situacao_final_id varchar(50)
);

insert into SITUACAO_FINAL values (3, 'Remanejado');
insert into SITUACAO_FINAL values (5, 'Transferido');
insert into SITUACAO_FINAL values (6, 'Reclassificado');

create table TURMAS_IDENTIFICACAO (
  id int not null,
  turma_id int
);

insert into TURMAS_IDENTIFICACAO values (1, 492);
insert into TURMAS_IDENTIFICACAO values (2, 493);
insert into TURMAS_IDENTIFICACAO values (3, 494);
```

#### Atualização (28/02/2018 21:30)

O autor pediu a separação dos dados por situação final. Exemplo prático colocado aqui: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b625e5/45/0

Pensei em quase todas as possibilidades :D

#### Novo SQL

```
-- Total geral
select
  'Total Estudantes' as Resultado, count(*)  as Total
from 
  ESTUDANTES_IDENTIFICACAO a
  inner join TURMAS_HAS_ESTUDANTES b on b.estudante_id = a.id
where
  b.turma_id = 492  
union
-- Busca total por situação final
select
  case 
    when b.situacao_final is null then 'Total Estudantes Sem Situação Final' 
    else 'Total Estudantes Com Situação Final' 
  end as Resultado, count(*)  as Total
from 
  ESTUDANTES_IDENTIFICACAO a
  inner join TURMAS_HAS_ESTUDANTES b on b.estudante_id = a.id
where
  b.turma_id = 492
group by
  case 
    when b.situacao_final is null then 'Total Estudantes Sem Situação Final' 
    else 'Total Estudantes Com Situação Final' 
  end  
union
-- Busca por sexo 
select 
  CONCAT('Sexo ', b.sexo), count(*) 
from 
  ESTUDANTES_IDENTIFICACAO a
  inner join SEXO_IDENTIFICACAO b on b.id = a.sexo_id
  inner join TURMAS_HAS_ESTUDANTES c on c.estudante_id = a.id
where
  c.turma_id = 492  
group by
  b.sexo
union
-- Busca total por situação final e sexo
select
  case 
    when c.situacao_final is null then CONCAT('Sexo ', b.sexo,' sem Situação Final') 
    else CONCAT('Sexo ', b.sexo, ' com Situação Final') 
  end as Resultado, count(*)  as Total
from 
  ESTUDANTES_IDENTIFICACAO a
  inner join SEXO_IDENTIFICACAO b on b.id = a.sexo_id
  inner join TURMAS_HAS_ESTUDANTES c on c.estudante_id = a.id
where
  c.turma_id = 492  
group by
  case 
    when c.situacao_final is null then CONCAT('Sexo ', b.sexo,' sem Situação Final') 
    else CONCAT('Sexo ', b.sexo, ' com Situação Final') 
  end   
union
-- Sexo e descricao da situação final
select 
  CONCAT('Sexo ', b.sexo, ' com situacao ', IFNULL(d.situacao_final_id, "ND")), count(*) 
from 
  ESTUDANTES_IDENTIFICACAO a
  inner join SEXO_IDENTIFICACAO b on b.id = a.sexo_id
  inner join TURMAS_HAS_ESTUDANTES c on c.estudante_id = a.id
  left join SITUACAO_FINAL d on d.id = c.situacao_final
where
  c.turma_id = 492    
group by
   CONCAT('Sexo ', b.sexo, ' com situacao ', IFNULL(d.situacao_final_id, "ND"))    
union
select 
  CONCAT('Situacao Final ', IFNULL(b.situacao_final_id, "ND")), count(*) 
from 
  TURMAS_HAS_ESTUDANTES a
  left join SITUACAO_FINAL b on b.id = a.situacao_final
where
  a.turma_id = 492  
group by
  b.situacao_final_id
```

Comment: Legal! Mas, como eu pego os dados de uma determinada turma? Eu posso colocar um WHERE. Ex.: WHERE turma_id = 492?

Comment: @LuisSouza isto mesmo, você pode usar `where` em cada um dos SQLs. Precisa de mais algum resultado diferente?

Comment: Eu coloquei o where a.id = 492 e continua pegando os valores da tabela toda

Comment: @LuisSouza fiz exemplo filtrando turma. Qualquer coisa dá um grito

Comment: Está retornando o total do sexo masculino e total do sexo feminino. Eu preciso do total descontando os que possuem os códigos na situação final (3,5 ou 6)

Comment: @LuisSouza está aqui a resposta final http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b625e5/9/0

Comment: @LuisSouza super resultado aqui http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b625e5/45/0 vê se falta algo :D

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que é isso que você está querendo, que retorna os totais para cada turma, agrupados pela turma:

```
SELECT
    TI.TURMA_ID,
    COUNT(THE.ESTUDANTE_ID) AS TOTAL ESTUDANTES,
    SUM(CASE WHEN EI.SEXOID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SEXO MASCULINO,
    SUM(CASE WHEN EI.SEXOID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SEXO FEMININO,
    SUM(CASE WHEN THE.SITUACAO_FINAL = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SITUACAO_FINAL_3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN THE.SITUACAO_FINAL = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SITUACAO_FINAL_5,
    SUM(CASE WHEN THE.SITUACAO_FINAL = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SITUACAO_FINAL_6    
FROM
    TURMAS_HAS_ESTUDANTES THE
INNER JOIN
    TURMAS_IDENTIFICACAO TI ON TI.ID = THE.TURMA_ID
INNER JOIN
    ESTUDANTES_IDENTIFICACAO EI ON EI.ID = THE.ESTUDANTES_IDENTIFICACAO_ID
INNER JOIN
    SEXO_IDENTIFICACAO SE ON SE.ID = EI.SEXO_ID
GROUP BY 
    TI.TURMA_ID
```

Me informa se deu o resultado esperado.

Comment: O resultado esperado na pergunta é apresentado em linhas e não em colunas. Outra coisa, se tiver mais uma situação na tabela `TURMAS_HAS_ESTUDANTES` o SQL não irá mostrar a nova situação

Comment: Achei legal a lógica que você empregou no SQL. +1

Comment: @Paulo R. F. Amorim Eu não entendi a linha: SEXO_IDENTIFICACAO SE ON SE.ID = EX.SEXO_ID Qual tabela é EX?

Comment: @LuisSouza Era pra ser **EI**, foi um erro de digitação, já está ajustado

Comment: @PauloR.F.Amorim O total de estudantes está aparecendo um número desconhecido.

Comment: @LuisSouza Na verdade estava errado era pra ser usado o **COUNT** ao invés do **SUM**, já fiz o ajuste

Comment: @PauloR.F.Amorim Eu testei aqui e retorna o número total de estudantes, o total de estudantes sexo masculino e feminino, o total por código mas, o meu problema é o seguinte. Eu preciso do total masculino e feminino descontando os códigos. Exemplo: 10 sexo feminino mas, 2 possui código 6 então o resultado deveria ser 8. Eu tenho o total do código mas, eu não sei se é masculino ou feminino

Answer (score 2):

Vou dar um exemplo de como construir isso usando um `select` de multiplos selects, mas você poderia também por os resultados também numa tabela temporária se quisesse:

```
select descricao, valor from 
(
    select 'TOTAL ESTUDANTES' descricao, count(*) valor from ESTUDANTES_IDENTIFICACAO
    union
    select 'SEXO MASCULINO' descricao,  count(*) valor from ESTUDANTES_IDENTIFICACAO where sexo_id=1
    union
    select 'SEXO FEMININO' descricao,  count(*) valor from ESTUDANTES_IDENTIFICACAO where sexo_id=2
    union
    select 'SITUAÇÃO FINAL 3' descricao,  count(*) valor from TURMAS_HAS_ESTUDANTES where situacaco_final-3
    -- e faz os outros union com selects baseados nos selects acima, um para cada total que você precisa
) valores
```